# In MySQL, how can I SELECT a column ONLY if all rows in that column are not null

Tags: mysql, sql

Sometimes there are some columns for particular outputs whereby the rows in a particular column are all null. This will vary on the specific query and these columns will sometimes indeed have varchar data in some or all of the rows - I therefore need a dynamic approach. In the case where all values in a column are null, the user doesn't need to know that all the row values are null, I just don't want this column to come out in the select at all.

As far as I know, you can't really query a whole column, just on a per-row basis? Test null counts with some aggregation data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns/fields included in the results of any given query must be static. You can simulate similar behavior in a stored procedure, but many frameworks that can use them (such as Crystal Reports) have issues when such behavior is encountered. It is generally a much better practice to keep such presentation concerns in the presentation "layer" (UI code).

Comment: Thanks for that statement upfront regarding the static field list. I am using a sproc for a resultset in Java that then uses Apache POI to export to excel. I might look on the Java and POI end for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple count on a column will give you the number of not null values in the column:

```
SELECT COUNT(col) FROM table)
```

Therefore, you are interesting in the above result being 0, meaning that 0 elements are not nulls or, in other words, all elements are nulls.

Then you can use the above query combined with a an IF or CASE statement, depending on your behaviour. As far as I know you cannot say select column or not, you need to have a fallback, meaning select the corresponding value of that column if ... condition, otherwise use this fallback value (e.g. 0, NULL, empty VARCHAR, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. In Java, I am converting the nulls to a dash, so cosmetically it looks right in the output excel. As Uueerdo pointed out, I will try on the presentation layer end of things.